# selecting a range within a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am using following VBA code (MS Excel 2010) to select a range of cells within a given range, to copy and insert the copied  cells back into the source range:
The range starts in the worksheet at row 2, down to row 2200 and from column 50 to 65.

`Set rngFEA = shtTarget.range("myrange")
iMaxLines = 20
With rngFEA
   .Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3 + iMaxLines, .Columns.Count)).Copy
    .Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3 + iMaxLines, .Columns.Count)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
 End With`

Doing it this way (no reference to rngFEA for the Cells(Row,Column) parameter) works fine, the selected cells are part of the range as expected.

I don't like use no reference for the cells() parameter, because using no reference makes the cells referring to the worksheet and rather give erroneous results, so I would rather like to use rngFEA.cells():

`Set rngFEA = shtTarget.range("myrange")
iMaxLines = 20
With rngFEA
   .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3 + iMaxLines, .Columns.Count)).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3 + iMaxLines, .Columns.Count)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
 End With`

BUT the resulting range lies well OUTSIDE the range rngFEA, somewhere off to the left and down.
I even could not find a relation between the used indexes and the resulting offset.

I believe the range.insert could also be stated as

```
rngFEA.cells(3,1).insert shift:=xldown
```

but this is not my concern right now.

I am well aware of the difference of referencing or not, but i do not understand why NOT using the reference to the range gives a correct result, and using the reference does not.

I expect

```
rngFEA.range(rngFEA.cells(1,1), rngFEA.cells(10,10))
```

to return the range of the topmost, leftmost cell of the given range down to the tenth cell to the right and down in the same range.
In the example code I select the leftmost cell in row 3 within the given range down to the 23rd cell and the right end of the range.
(the actually selected row is row 3 in the workbook and hence row 2 in the range)
I looked into Microsofts Informations and several forums, but could not find an explanation which describes this effect sufficiently.

I know that

```
range.row
```

returns the number of the row in the WORKSHEET where the range starts,

```
range.column
```

returns the column where the range starts.

Selecting a cell or a row within the given range

```
range.row(2)
```

does not return the second row of the range but the second row of the worksheet. A

```
for each myrow in range.rows
```

the index

```
myrow.row
```

returns the number of the row within the range, but using it as the selecting index seems to return the row within the worksheet, so I need to add

```
range.row + myrow.row
```

to index to the actual row within the range.

The mechanics behind this and the above described behaviors of selecting a range within a range are confusing to me.
Since there are many ways to handle things in Excel using VBA, I hope you can give me a general explanation of the described behavior rather than a solution (if not for explaining the why) :)

THX in advance

Ydalir

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can confirm this behavior:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("C3:H28")

    'This selects E5:F6 (???)
    With rng
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Select
    End With


    'This selects C3:D4 (expected)
    With rng
        rng.Parent.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Seems like it may be related to the "double relative" combination of using both `.Range` and `.Cells`

Instead using `rng.Parent.Range` and having only the `.Cells` be relative to the containing range seems to fix it (and still allows for fully-qualified range references)

Comment: Heya Tim,

thanks for your input.
I will use your solution :) 

I still would like to know, why excel acts that way.
May be the behavior is correct but I do not see a system behind that.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same behavior when getting an Excel range within a range in VB.Net. [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39044383/2043436) solved the weird behavior. At first I though it had something to do with the use of `With` but I guess it had something to do with the double relative referencing of dot notation as Tim had suggested.

```
Public Sub SomeMergingFunction(ByRef inputRange As Excel.Range)
    With inputRange
        Debug.Print(.Address) ' $A$4:$A$130 correct
        Debug.Print(.Cells(1, 1).Address) ' $A$4 correct
        Debug.Print(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1)).Address) ' $A$7 wrong
        Debug.Print(.Parent.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1)).Address) ' $A$4 correct
    End With
End Sub
```