# Excel VBA: Using .Range.Offset property on a range variable returns unexpected values

Tags: excel, variables, range, offset, vba

I have given Stack Exchange and Google a good search and I can't find the *exact* answer I'm looking for.

I'm having trouble understanding the values returned from using RangeVariable.Range.Offset, NOT Worksheet.Range.Offset

I define a range from A2 to J10, so skipping the first row:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", "J10")
```

So now I test using .Offset(0 rows, 9 columns):

```
MsgBox myRange.Range("A1").Offset(0, 9).Address
```

I return "$J$2" as expected, seeing as "A1" of this range is "A2" on the sheet itself.

But now I use the above as the second argument of another .Range property test:

```
MsgBox myRange.Range("A1", myRange.Range("A1").Offset(0, 9)).Address
```

I return "$A$2:$J$3", so it looks like its skipped a row calculating the second argument, and it ends up being a 2 row range even though the row offset was zero.

If I change the row offset to -1 it returns "$A$2:$J$2", so only the one row.

I usually use Worksheet.Range to define ranges and it always works as expected.
Can anybody think why using a RangeVariable.Range.Offset for the second argument of a range property might work this way?

Cheers, Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely remember a previous question along these lines and i don't recall if it was answered, but this gives the expected output:

```
Range(myRange.Range("A1"), myRange.Range("A1").Offset(0, 9)).Address
```

EDIT: this was it - [selecting a range within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036185/selecting-a-range-within-a-range/39044383#39044383)

EDIT2:  I'd find this easier to work with  -

```
myRange.Range("A1").Resize(1,10).Address
```

Comment: Hi Tim, that's spot-on what I was after. I now have a better looking macro, I hate fudging logic just to get the right output. Using a row offset value of -1 to stay on the same row just looked ugly. Big Thanks!