# Excel VBA Code pastes result into wrong range

Tags: excel, vba

A script that copies a range into another range. However, when I try to copy the range from Sheet1 to Sheet2 the result won't be pasted into column J, it get pasted with an offset of 8 columns (column R). I cant understand why? Both RowCountSummary and ColumnCountSummary are set to 0, i.e. first index of the range?

```
Sub InsertForecastData()

  Dim ColumnsCount As Integer
  Dim ColCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsCount As Integer
  Dim ForeCastRange As Range
  Dim ForecastWS As Worksheet
  Dim SummaryWs As Worksheet
  Dim PasteRange As Range
  Dim ColumnCountSummary As Integer
  Dim RowCountSummary As Integer

  ColumnsCount = 300
  ColCounter = 0
  RowsCount1 = 0
  RowsCount2 = 47
  ColumnCountSummary = 0
  RowCountSummary = 0

  Do While ColCounter <= ColumnsCount

  Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
  Set ForeCastRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:KN49")
  With ForeCastRange
    .Range(.Cells(RowsCount1, ColCounter), .Cells(RowsCount2, ColCounter)).Copy
  End With

  Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
  Set PasteRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J2:J13915")
  With PasteRange
    .Range(.Cells(RowCountSummary, ColumnCountSummary), .Cells(RowCountSummary + RowsCount2, ColumnCountSummary)).PasteSpecial
  End With

  RowCountSummary = RowCountSummary + 48
  ColCounter = ColCounter + 1

  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not quite understand how you meant that I should change my code. Could you please write it out?

Comment: But If I change it to just .PasteSpecial, I will paste the result in "J2" and 48 rows down to "J50". Next iteration will write over the previous iteration's result. I want the next iterations's result to be pasted starting from "J51" to "J98". That's why I use the .Cells property in order to refer to a range within the range.  However, I don't understand why I get an offset of 8 columns?

Comment: Let me check your code and come back to you. gimme sometime

Comment: For reasons I don't fully understand, if you remove the dot in front of `range` in your `pasterange` definition it will paste in I (not J because you refer to relative column 0). Btw make sure you declare all your variables.

Comment: In fact I don't understand at all.

Comment: This is a combination of using ..range.range [see here] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range) and having zeros for row and column numbers. The fix which is to add .parent is here [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036185/selecting-a-range-within-a-range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour has been encountered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036185/selecting-a-range-within-a-range) and can seen with this simple demo

```
Sub test()
  With Sheet1.Range("J3:J100")
    Debug.Print .Range(.Cells(0, 0), .Cells(47, 0)).Address
  End With
End Sub
```

which results in $R$4:$R$51. If you repeat run for the columns B to J the results are B,D,F,H,J,L,N,P showing the doubling effect. B is OK I think because of the zero column number.

You can probably fix your code by setting RowCountSummary = 1 and ColumnCountSummary = 1 and adding .parent

```
With PasteRange
  .Parent.Range(.Cells(RowCountSummary, ColumnCountSummary), _
  .Cells(RowCountSummary + RowsCount2, ColumnCountSummary)).PasteSpecial
```

End With

or you could try this

```
Sub InsertForecastData1()

  Const columnCount As Integer = 3
  Const rowCount As Integer = 48
  Const sourceCol As String = "B"
  Const targetCol As String = "J"
  Const startRow As Integer = 2
  Const records As Integer = 300

  Dim rngSource as Range, rngTarget As Range
  Dim start as Single, finish as Single
  Set rngSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(sourceCol & startRow)
  Set rngSource = rngSource.Resize(rowCount, columnCount)
  Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(targetCol & startRow)

  start = Timer
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To records
    'Debug.Print rngSource.Address, rngTarget.Address
    rngSource.Copy rngTarget
    Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(rowCount, 0)
    Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(rowCount, 0)
  Next i

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  finish = Timer
  MsgBox "Completed " & records & " records in " & finish - start & " secs"

End Sub
```

See Remarks section the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range)